# Firebug can't choose script

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug, inline

I messed something up.  In firebug I select the scipts tab, then click on inline and select the script I would like to step through with some break points.  I am reasonably sure I have done this with the script before.

Now after removing and reinstalling firebug, clearing cache etc., scratching my head, when I select any of the scripts, the script briefly shows up and then immediately drops back to the HTML page that includes the script.  If I'm quick, when I select the script I can scroll down and when I stop, it scrolls up, on it's own, line by line and when it reaches the top it goes back to the HTML page that has included the script

So from the screenshot, there are some js scripts below (cropped them out, didn't want to share the names).  I've tried checking and un-checking inline with now result.  I have a feeling it's related to my swiss cheese knowledge of js and web programming.

[image]

Comment: the only inline javascript is some jquery and the script I want to look at is included in the head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure how can further can I assist without having to see the live site or some codes that may point to some explanation. However, here are some tricks that might help.

I use FirefoxAurora that comes with a tab called Changes. or maybe I install the Firebug extension somewhere. I forgot. But googling it up, this may be it [Firediff](http://www.incaseofstairs.com/firediff/).

The tab looks like the image attached and it will Diff the changes inside a page and then you might have a clue what's going on. It's detect element/attributes changes (not sure about inline script).

P/s: Somehow it doesn't work now, forgot how I've tested before. The url above have more explanation on this. But do check it out. Its been useful to me last time.

[image: Firebug Changes extension tab]

Comment: ah. i see. the problem is with your Firebug extension? sometimes i'm trying hard to answer SO question so quick, I missed something. :D. does Chrome console helps?

Comment: yes, chrome does, I like to switch back and forth sometimes.  I installed a bug fix from this page http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5134 and it did the trick.

Comment: i see. good one rd42, thanks for sharing. just in case me/anyone encounter the same issue. +1 on your comment.

Answer (score 2):

I hate to answer my own question, but I don't want to leave this post incomplete, so feel to improve on the answer.  I don't plan to give myself the check unless there appears to be no further activity.  I found a bug fix at [issue #5134](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5134), and installed the 1.10.0a6 update found [here](http://getfirebug.com/releases/firebug/1.10/firebug-1.10.0a6.xpi) and one last thing, the auto-scrolling stopped when I toggled the "Break on next" button pictured below. (the yellow pause button below the firebug.

[image]